# Emails always queued with status 250

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

My application uses Simple E-mail Service from AWS + GoogleMail for sending mails to clients.

But I have a lot of complaints about mail never received, even after more than 24 hours.

In the logs, I see:

> 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXX
>   reportingMTA: a9-82.smtp-out.amazonses.com

Can anyone tell me:

- Is e-mail queued on Amazon OR on recipient server?
- Where can I find rules to help me avoid that?

Comment: *"In the logs"* ... which "logs" are you referring to?  Also, do you have SES delivery/bounce/complaint notifications configured?

Comment: yep those ones, ses logs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means Amazon 'did their job' by delivering the message and having it accepted.

What implies that you shouldn't want to avoid this to happen.

The problem is, as [Amazon says](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html):

> Amazon SES successfully delivers the email to the recipient's mail
>   server. This notification **does not indicate that the actual recipient
>   received the email** because Amazon SES **cannot control what happens to
>   an email after the receiving mail server accepts it**. Delivery
>   notifications are available only through Amazon SNS.

I was in the very situation you are, I had some complaints about never receiving the message. What I realized after a lot of analysis:

- There was in fact emails that after being said as delivered, later on came back as 'marked as spam' messages -> I asked them to whitelist my domain
- I myself had a flaw in my verification of whether to send email to a client or not ( I was blacklisting all recipients in a batch if any of them sent back a "Permanent Bounce" response)
- There was even cases of people saying that didn't receive (because they heard that some other people weren't actually receiving)  and investigating further I found out they had in fact received but were just too lazy to take a look to give me correct information (!)
- I found many types of "Successfully delivered notifications" (such as "`250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXX`", "`250 ok:  Message XXXXXXX accepted`", "`250 2.6.0 Queued mail for delivery`", etc) and I thought there could be a problem related to this "queued" responses, but in the end I found none.

My advice is that you investigate further other possible reasons just like I did.

Comment: Adding to the troubleshooting list here for anyone else looking for answers on this matter.. check your 'From' & 'Reply-To' parts in the header, you cannot have any other addresses there other than your server's. Might be obvious to some, but was an issue on my side